# Android 23 don't show log

Tags: android, logging, kotlin

I seeked around but didn't find solution to this problem. I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 and Kotlin. Logcat is setted to the proper device and debug level, the filter if the same for the 2 API versions.

Using Android 28 my app logs regularly:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Timber.d("onCreate()")

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video)

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        with(savedInstanceState) {
            mPlayWhenReady = getBoolean(KEY_PLAY_WHEN_READY)
            mCurrentWindow = getInt(KEY_WINDOW)
            mPlaybackPosition = getLong(KEY_POSITION)
        }
    }

    mShouldAutoPlay = true

    mMediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        this,
        Util.getUserAgent(this, "VideoBook4Kids"),
        BANDWIDTHMETER as TransferListener<in DataSource>
    )
}
```

But if I launch the app with a API level 23 no logs anymore!

Someone can help me to understand where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** upgrading Android Studio to 3.3 the logcat works fine!

Comment: Already I faced the above issue that time I restart my android studio, I can view the logs, Can you try this?

Comment: just restart the Android studio or unplug and plug your phone device

Comment: No, restarting android studio, unplug and plug the phone didn't fix the problem... ;(

Comment: After updated Android Studio to 3.3 this bug is fixed, now I have the log regularly.